# Restrict partner to display in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view

I want to add record level restriction in odoo. I want display just that `partners` to `current login user` which `state_id` equals to `state_id of current login user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to add **Record Rule** from **Settings/Technical/Security/Record Rules** menu. In that you have to set object as Partner (res.partner). Need to set Rule Definition(Domain Filter) like below code and just save it.

[('state_id','=',user.partner_id.state_id.id)]

Comment: From which user you are tried. Have you tried from other than admin user ?

Comment: Any rule is not apply or working to admin user. You must have to login from other user. Admin user can access all data, he has super rights.

Comment: can you tell me please how can i login with demo user in localhost because i am very beginner in odoo

Comment: but still all pertner  are displaying

Comment: Open demo user.  You will see More button in middle of screen. Click on that. You can see "Change Password" click on that and set password whatever you want to set for demo user. Logout from admin user. Login with demo user, in that Enter Email/Login = demo and password = whatever password you set.

Comment: What is Object =? in Record rule you have created ?

Comment: object name is `res.partner`

Comment: it is giving me this error in demo user `AccessError

The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.

(Document type: res.users, Operation: read) `

Comment: thanks it is done with this code...  `[('state_id.id','=',user.partner_id.state_id.id)]` thanks again...

Comment: but now it is `restricting` that `user` to `create new partner`  i want to remove that restriction..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115184/discussion-between-nilesh-sheliya-and-tahir-noor).

Comment: Open Record rule that you have created and tick "Apply for Create".

Comment: and how can i use another domain with it with `and operation`

Comment: I want display just that partners which state_id.id and parent_id.id same as user's.